# Postfix: Handling bounced email where both From: and To: addresses are illegitimate?

Tags: email, postfix

We have two Postfix mailservers in a University environment. There are thousands of servers managed by a dozen different groups, and I do not control all of the hosts. These servers use my mailservers for routing email, either as a Smarthost or using MX records.

Several servers are continuously sending email where the from address is like:

```
cfengine@host.example.org
```

These emails are sent to an invalid address, and thus bounce. But since the "From:" address is also invalid, the emails are stuck in an endless bounce loop for several days.

If I list the postfix queue with `postqueue -p` shows me hundreds of messages like the following:

```
ABCD7301713E     3799 Tue Mar  5 05:20:35  MAILER-DAEMON
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to host.example.org[192.168.100.100]:25: Connection refused)
                                         cfengine@host.example.org
```

1. Using Postfix on the mailservers, is it possible to rewrite either the "From:" address or the "To:" address in these emails? I would like to direct them to the system owners and request that they clean up their systems.
2. Can I notify Postmaster about these bounces? Postmaster can then notify the system owners.

Answer (score 4):

Once solution is to notify *somebody* about the bounces. postmaster is sometimes used for this task. The parameters [notify_classes](http://postfixmail.com/blog/index.php/explanation-of-notify_classes-in-postfix/) and `bounce_notice_recipient` may allow me to notify the postmaster that bounces are happening.

The bounce message may contain the Hostname & IP of the host which is attempting to deliver the email. If not, the administrator can run the `postcat` command on the Message-Id and see the contents of the message (headers and all). From here, we can contact the system owner and ask them to fix the problem on their side.

> **bounce** (also implies **2bounce**)
>
> Send the postmaster copies of the headers of bounced mail, and send transcripts of SMTP sessions when Postfix rejects mail. The notification is sent to the address specified with the bounce_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
>
> **2bounce**
>
> Send undeliverable bounced mail to the postmaster. The notification is sent to the address specified with the 2bounce_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default:
>   postmaster).
>
> **bounce_notice_recipient (default: postmaster)**
>
> The recipient of postmaster notifications with the message headers of mail that Postfix
>   did not deliver and of SMTP conversation transcripts of mail that Postfix did not
>   receive. This feature is enabled with the notify_classes parameter.
>
> **2bounce_notice_recipient (default: postmaster)**
>
> The recipient of undeliverable mail that cannot be returned to the sender. This feature is enabled with the notify_classes parameter.

Comment: One should always have a functioning `postmaster` address for the domain, which someone in operations reads regularly. In this case it shouldn't be hard to find the machine from where the email originated (it's a few days ago in the log entries) and then hunt down the owner of the machine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton We do have a postmaster address, and it is monitored. But the default Postfix configuration does not deliver bounce notifications to this address, which is somewhat surprising.

Comment: Not at all surprising. On a production mail server with any significant volume, sending bounce notices would flood the postmaster mailbox. That's what that the log is for.

Answer (score 2):

**Have you considered rejecting messages with an invalid envelope sender in the SMTP session?**

---

You could choose one of the following:

- add "unresponsive host" to [access table](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) with REJECT action
- use [policy filter](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html).
  *The file `examples/smtpd-policy/greylist.pl` in the Postfix source tree implements a simplified greylist policy server*
- use custom [milter](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html)
  [MIMEDefang.org](http://MIMEDefang.org/) milter lets you express your filtering policies in Perl — it is worth considering if you plan to also add spam/virus filtering

---

In my opinion, session rejecting is what *should* be done in SMTP, but too frequently it is not done for non-technical reasons.

Comment: Would this reject email sent from within my network which does not match a specified pattern?

Comment: Yes *in simple cases*. I think you would prefer functionality provided by policy filters or milter filters. AFAIK milters can rewrite envelope sender address.

Comment: If there's a relatively small pool of incorrect addresses, you could use a canonical map to rewrite them so eg cfengine@whatever becomes somthing@deliverable ....

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Bouncing would be best though - don't accept it!